# Proof $3\mid xy$ if and only if $3\mid x$ or $3\mid y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

State whether the following statement is true and give a proof.

For every integer $x,y$: $(xy\mid 3)$ if and only if $3\mid x$ or $3\mid y$

I get that this statement is true the product of 2 numbers is divisible by $3$ only if one of the numbers $x$ or $y$ is divisible by $3$. However how do I prove it algebraically?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Apply the def: what does it mean that e.g. $3|x$ ?

Comment: Mauro (and I) mean that your formulas aren't as readable as we would want. At least for me, lots of your symbols are just empty squares. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math on this site. That way you don't rely on people having the right character decoding packs in their browsers.

Comment: Why did you use another notation in the body, for example $x/3$ instead of $3\mid x$ ?

Comment: In the title you have $3|x$ while in the text there is $x|3$: the two are not the same….

Comment: sorry I was on 2 hrs sleep and got very tired i was supposed to write 3|x sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, if $p$ is a prime and $x,y$ are integers, then if $p$ divides $xy$, then $p$ divides $x$ or $p$ divides $y$.

Suppose $p$ is not a divisor of $x$. Then since $p$ is prime, $p$ and $x$ have non common nontrivial divisor, i.e., $\gcd(p,x)=1$. By the extended Euclidean algorithm,

$1=ap+bx$

for some integers $a,b$. Thus

$y = ayp+bxy.$

Then $p$ divides the right-hand side $ayp+bxy$, since $p$ divides $xy$ by hypothesis. Hence, $p$ divides the left-hand side, which is $y$. Done.